# Performing a command with Makefiles twice without having to type it twice

Tags: makefile, latex

I'm using `make` to build a PDF from LaTeX source, as follows:

```
PDF:=lualatex --output-directory=../pdf
TITLE:="report"

.PHONY: pdf

pdf: ./src/report.tex
    cd ./src && $(PDF) report.tex $(TITLE).pdf
    cd ./src && $(PDF) report.tex $(TITLE).pdf

clean:
    rm -rf ./pdf/* ./tex/*.aux ./tex/*.log
```

The doubled-up command under the `pdf` rule is necessary to get the cross-references and citations in the report right. Is there a way to do this *without* having to have that command doubled-up like that?

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you invoke latex from the command line (i.e. without Make)? The use of a makefile seems superfluous to this question.

Comment: You should look into using [`latexmk`](http://ctan.org/pkg/latexmk) instead of pure `make`.

Comment: @Beta Hardly - this is a general problem with LaTeX, due to its single-pass nature. However, what I would like to be able to do is tell Make to run a command twice without literally having to type it twice. It's a question regarding replacing boilerplate, and thus, is hardly superfluous.

Comment: The commands given in the Makefile are just executed by the shell. So, just use a `for` loop of your shell.